# Memory Leak in sample project

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

I have downloaded the finished sample project which can be downloaded here http://www.raywenderlich.com/downloads/Cocos2DSimpleGame3_v2.zip

from Ray Wenderlichs tutorial site http://www.raywenderlich.com/25806/harder-monsters-and-more-levels-how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-2-x-part-3

I have put it on my device and noticed that my iphone memory got full after a while. I used xcode to test for memory leaks (product -> profile) and it showed that there are numerous memory leaks in the program. I'm very new to cocos2d so I don't know how to fix them. Is someone able to help fix these memory leak issues? Please keep in mind I'm a novice. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this may not be what you want, but you should consider converting the project to ARC.
What you should do is add the Cocos2d (and whatever other lib files with it) to a static library. Once this is done, convert your project to ARC using Xcode.

ARC will handle the memory management for you. When ARC is turned on, the compiler will insert the appropriate memory management statements such as retain and release messages. It is best to use ARC as the compiler has a better idea of an object's life cycle and is less prone to human error. This will also save you many potential hours scouring over that sample project.

There is a wonderful tutorial posted here on how to convert Cocos2D projects to ARC http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/

Comment: Thanx for that, I'm trying to follow along but I noticed that when I create the new library and am editing the Search Path, User Header Search Paths isn't there. What do I do? Now my program won't build and run :/

Comment: What version of xcode are you running? Are you sure you are looking in the right place?

Comment: all good, I managed to find it and got it all working. Cheers for that